# How to set maximal execution time of operation

Tags: arduino-uno, json, error

I'm JSON deserializing output from ESP8266 in  my Arduino UNO, but when it fails (for some reason every time after it deserializes successfully) the program lags for few seconds and I don't want that to happen (at least not for a long time)

```
#include "SevSeg.h"
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
SevSeg sevseg; 

StaticJsonDocument<500> response;

String data;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(74880);
  Serial.setTimeout(10000);
  while (!Serial) {
     // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
  byte numDigits = 4;
  byte digitPins[] = {2, 3, 4, 5};
  byte segmentPins[] = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};
  bool resistorsOnSegments = false; // 'false' means resistors are on digit pins
  byte hardwareConfig = COMMON_ANODE; // See README.md for options
  bool updateWithDelays = false; // Default 'false' is Recommended
  bool leadingZeros = false; // Use 'true' if you'd like to keep the leading zeros
  bool disableDecPoint = false; // Use 'true' if your decimal point doesn't exist or isn't connected. Then, you only need to specify 7 segmentPins[]

  sevseg.begin(hardwareConfig, numDigits, digitPins, segmentPins, resistorsOnSegments,
  updateWithDelays, leadingZeros, disableDecPoint);
  Serial.println("running");

}

void loop(){

       if (Serial.available()) {
            Serial.write(Serial.read());
            const auto deser_err = deserializeJson(response, Serial);
       
            if (!deser_err) {
                
                if(response["type"] == "num"){
                  sevseg.setNumber(response["data"],response["dot"]);
                }else{
                  sevseg.setChars(response["data"]);
                }
                String data = response["data"];
                Serial.println(data);

            }else{
              Serial.print(F("Failed to deserialize, reason: \""));
              Serial.print(deser_err.c_str());
              Serial.println('"');
            }
            
       
  
      }

  sevseg.refreshDisplay();


}
```

The response

```
running  //runs everytime I turn on the arduino
21:43:03.797 -> {null
21:43:03.797 -> :null
21:43:03.797 -> ,null
21:43:03.797 -> :null
21:43:03.797 -> ,null
21:43:03.797 -> :Failed to deserialize, reason: "InvalidInput" // for some reason I have to send request 2 times because for the first time it always fails
21:43:03.797 -> 
Uove //correct data received
21:43:04.772 -> // this timestamp isn't right it is like 5 seconds after correct data
Failed to deserialize, reason: "EmptyInput"
```

What can I do for this not to happen for the first time or in a shorter duration?

I'd be really thankful for any answer.

Comment: so, the program does something different when it deserializes successfuly and you want to know why it does something different?

Comment: Yes that too, I have a lot of questions about this weird behaviour

Comment: What exactly are you sending over serial? The first character will be echoed back over Serial. It does not get used by the deseriallzation. That might be a problem depending on what you are sending.

Comment: Do you know, what the timeout of the deserialization from serial is? That timeout is propably what takes so long.

Comment: I don't know and i couldn't find it either, but I've noticed that the lower `Serial.setTimeout` the shorter the duration of waiting, but when u set it too low, it doesn't want to deserialize anything (the current 10s is minimum for it to work correctly)

Comment: I think you shouldn't deserialize directly from Serial. Instead send the json data with a newline character at the end, read the data into a buffer, until you read the newline character. Then do the deserialization on that buffer. Currently you are clearly butchering the json string. You still didn't write, what exactly you are sending via serial. Please include that information in your question

Comment: remove the big timeout. add `while (Serial.read() != -1);` after deserializeJson to read out the newline characters which cause to enter the deserialization without data. and remove `Serial.write(Serial.read());`